# How do I install `setroubleshoot-server` (sealert)

Tags: linux, selinux

I am looking to use `sealert` on my Debian env.

I am unable to find the package to install to have it and the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As sealert need setroubleshootd, and setroubleshootd is not yet in Debian, you need to compile them if you need them. There is an article here : https://wiki.debian.org/ReleaseGoals/SELinux where the write propose a "Nice to have".

Comment: Maybe it's my searching skills that sucks but where do I find the source code? Thank you :)

Comment: I found https://github.com/fedora-selinux/setroubleshoot/ Never tested

Comment: Thanks... I'll try to make it work.